# How do you pronounce coitus?

Tags: pronunciation

Everywhere I've checked for pronunciations online it's CO-IT-TUS. Every time I've heard someone use it in real life it's COY-TIS. Since so many people pronounce it in the latter form, does that mean the original pronunciation is "dead"?

Comment: Where did you hear this and where are all these _many people_?

Comment: CO-IT-TUS sounds too much like an alarming venereal disease, which could explain the decay of this pronunciation.

Comment: OED gives it as */ˈkəʊɪtʌs/* (presumably, OP's first rendering). But the word's not *that* common, so people who mainly only see it in written form (esp., as *coitus interruptus*) will tend to use what looks like the more credible *coy-tus* version.

Comment: This is in any standard dictionary, but you need only listen to Dr Sheldon Cooper to assure yourself that *coitus* is a rhyme for *exploit us* — and a [feminine rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminine_rhyme), no less. :)

Comment: I always wondered why Sheldon pronounced it thus. Perhaps he had only ever encountered it in books...

Comment: I learned it in grammer school sex education as co-ee-tus - and always thought it appeared in the lyrics to the Eagles' "Hotel California": *On a dark desert highway, cool wind in my hair
 Warm smell of **colitas**, rising up through the air."* lol! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where both pronunciations are correct. CO-it-tus is indeed the traditional pronunciation, as backed up by OED (see FumbleFingers' comment above). However, COY-tis has become the default pronunciation, probably because of people who see the written form guessing at the pronunciation (as suggested by FumbleFingers again and mplungjan). As both versions are in relatively heavy use (considering how infrequently the word arises), then it seems clear that both versions are currently correct. In a generation, it's quite possible that the CO-it-tus variation will have died out, as you suppose has happened already, but evidence appears to show that it is not the case yet.